# Bundle in onConnect method of ConnectionCallback always returned null after connected to Google+ Account

Tags: android, google-plus

I followed [Integrating Google+ into your Android app](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started)

But I have issue `Bundle always null` when returned to me.

I dont know how to `get all information related to my Google+ account` if Bundle returned null.

So `how Bundle is not return null`.

Please help me,

Thanks,

**UPDATE** I just know how to get information related to my account by using following code :

```
    @Override
public void onConnected() {
  ...
  if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
    Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
    String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
    String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
  }
}
```

Anyway, I dont know the `Bundle was returned` for doing what's thing?

p/s : This is the codes :

`Java code` :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.fragment_create_account);

/**
 * Initial Google Plus authentication
 */
mGap = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(Plus.API)
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
        .build();
```

}

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    // TODO BUNDLE ALWAYS RETURN NULL
    Log.i("", "onConnected " + bundle);
    if (bundle != null)
        Log.i("", "bundle " + bundle.size() + " " + bundle.toString());
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i("", "onConnectionFailed ");
    if (!mIntentInProgress && connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            startIntentSenderForResult(connectionResult.getResolution().getIntentSender(),
                                                     0, null, 0, 0, 0);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
            // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGap.connect();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i("", "onConnectionSuspended " + i);
}
```

`Manifest.xml file` :

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

`build.grade` file :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
```

Comment: @ Mirror Towers Did you get any idea for this null Bundle value ?

Comment: u can see in Update of the question? It can get value, not null anymore

Comment: what changes you have made from the previous?

Comment: Oh sorry, i misunderstood. I have no idea with this `null Bundle`. What I want is information & I can get it by using the other way, so no need to notice this `null Bundle` value any more.

Answer (score 0):

This [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.html#onConnected(android.os.Bundle)) says "Note that the contents of the connectionHint Bundle are defined by the specific services...and May be null if no content is provided by the service".  Personally I don't use that bundle.

Once you are connected, you can get other information (like people in the user's circles) as outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people).

Answer (score 0):

Hope you implemented `ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult>` interface.

In OnResult() method I did like this to retrieve the user details as follows.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult> {
...
 @Override
    public void onResult(People.LoadPeopleResult loadPeopleResult) {
        getDisplayName(loadPeopleResult);
        getProfileInformation();
    }
...
 private void getProfileInformation() {
    Log.d(TAG,"getProfileInformation method called from onResult");
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            Person.Image personPhoto = currentPerson.getImage();
            String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
            String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();

            Log.d(TAG,"Google Plus user Details :"+"\nPerson Name :"+personName+"\nEmail :"+email+"\npersonGooglePlusProfile:"+personGooglePlusProfile);

        }

    }
```

Still I am getting the null Bundle even I tried again to connect in OnActivityForResult method

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG,"Google onActivityResult called");
        if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have followed the [Google Developers link](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started)